# know google maps stop moving xamarin android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to update the value of a marker when the maps stop moving, but I can´t detect it. Does someone know how?. I already tried with the PanGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `GoogleMap.IOnCameraIdleListener` and assign it to your map instance (assumably in the `MapReady` callback):

#### Implement `GoogleMap.IOnCameraIdleListener`

```
public void OnCameraIdle()
{
    // a callback that is invoked when camera movement has ended.
}
```

#### Assign the Idle listener to the `GoogleMap` instance:

```
googleMap.SetOnCameraIdleListener(this);
```

Re: [setOnCameraIdleListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setOnCameraIdleListener(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener))

Comment: I used nativemap instead of googlemap, beacuase I don't have a googleMap object, but the code doesn't work.

Comment: @GuillermoGómezSánchez `nativemap` ? Add your code to your question as you have it tagged as GoogleMaps

Comment: I checked it out (I use nativemap because I use xamarin, sorry I didn't know I put android alone), it works, but it looks that it cycles when I use it, I will look what can I do

Comment: I use it to display a pin in the map when the map stop moving but I can't get a window that is displayed when the pin is touched

Comment: I added a boolean because public void OnCameraIdle() activates when I stop the map and later of displaying the info window of a marker. I put it in this format

Comment: if(boolean){
//update info of pin with actual position and street
boolean = false;
}

else{boolean=true;}

Comment: Thanka a lot SushiHangover